# Using PHP variables as parameters for JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, string, quotes, quoting

I'm having a bit of trouble working with the quotations for this. So, let's make an example of sending two strings we want concatenated through variables, and then running them through a JavaScript function to concatenate them (I understand that this is very basic in PHP and I know how to do it, I'm just using this example for the sake of simplicity).

JavaScript Code:

```
function con(first, last) {
    answer = first+last;
    alert(answer);
    return;
}
```

HTML and PHP:

```
<?php
    $first = "Butter";
    $last = "Last";
    echo '<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con(".$first.", ".$last.")" />';
?>
```

This code above does not work, how can I make it work?

Thanks all

Comment: Have you considered using ajax ?

Comment: How could I use ajax to solve this? I want the variables from PHP, because in my actual webpage they are session variables

Comment: Update `echo '<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con(".$first.", ".$last.")" />';` into `echo "<input type='button' value='Get Answer' onclick='con(\"$first\", \"$last\");' />";`

Comment: Thank you! If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as solved. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the html that that's generating it will be something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con(".$first.", ".$last.")" />
```

Which as you can see is not correct.

There are a couple of issues with your code, first of all, variables names, like $first won't get evaluated to their value if they are inside single quotes.

Try:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con("'.$first.'", "'.$last.'")" />';
```

This will output :

```
<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con("Butter", "Last")" />
```

which is still not correct, as you're not passing the arguments to your javascript function correctly.

Try:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con(\''.$first.'\', \''.$last.'\')" />';
```

which should output

```
<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick="con('Butter', 'Last')" />
```

that hopefully works :)

Comment: Your answer works perfectly! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

JavaScript Code:

```
function con(first, last) {
answer= first+last;
alert(answer);
return;}
```

PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php
 $first = "Butter";
 $last = "Last";
 echo '<input type="button" value="Get Answer" onclick=con("'.$first.'","'.$last.'") />';?>
```

when you pass the value to the javascript function through php you must pass the value in 'single quote' or "double quote" like onclick=con("'.$first.'","'.$last.'");